# Java 8, JSP - should put Optional object in request.setAttribute() or session.setAttribute()?

Tags: jsp, servlets, serialization, java-8, option-type

I realized that Java Optional Ojbect is not Serializable. I also realized the main intend of using Optional object is for the method return type.

Given the following method:

```
public Phone(){
    public Optional<Phone> getPhone(){
          // some logic goes here to create a new phone object and then put it in optional...
    }
}
```

In a client class, it calls the above method to retrieve an Optional object and then pass it to request so that the front-end JSP page can use this object:

```
Optional<Phone> optionalPhone = (new Phone()).getPhone();
// 1. put Optional object in request/session.
request.setAttribute("optionalPhone ", optionalPhone );
// or 2. put Phone object in request/session.
request.setAttribute("phoneObject", optionalPhone.get());
```

Questions:

1. Should we pass Optional object in request to the front-end JSP, or pass the value of Optional object (i.e. Phone object)?
2. As for the former option, Optional is not serializable, so it will not work in distributed systems (session replications, etc.). Please correct me if I am wrong on this.
3. If I pass the Phone object instead of Optional object into request, does that mean I would need to use Optional.get() method? I heard that we should always avoid using isPresent() and get() methods when using Optional.

In the case of #3, is it better to use the following codes (in order to avoid using get() method)?

```
//put Phone object in request/session.
request.setAttribute("phoneObject", optionalPhone.orElseGet(Phone::new));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. What's the use of an optional attribute if it needs to be set? Just don't if the `Optional<Phone>` is `None`.
2. see 1.
3. It doesn't. The pattern would rather be something along the lines of:

   ```
   getPhone()
       .map(phone -> Request.withPhone(phone))
       .orElse(Request.withoutPhone())
   ```

   Using `isPresent` and `get` is adviced against as it is not the idiomatic (declarative) way to deal with an `Optional`. Compare that e.g. with my (pseudo-codish) suggestion.

Comment: can you please provide more details on Request.withPhone() or withoutPhone() method? The main purpose of the question here is to understand the correct way to pass a data object to JSP page by using Optional.

Comment: Sry, I thought the main purpose was how to properly deal with `Optional`, indicated by the last part of the 3rd question. May I ask what the receiver of the request looks like? I understand an optional attribute to be either present or not, hence just doing nothing in case the `Optional` is empty (`None` as opposed to `Some(value)`).